# Pymongo : Aggregate Date Range Query with Date as String

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection as below :
sample
{'_id': {'day': '2020-12-04', 'device': {'device': 'DH002'}},
'value': {'average': 44.5, 'max': 50, 'min': 38}}

Issue a: Am trying to query this collection basis the date range inputted by user.The query is as below.The issue is that I get output only for the start date instead of the entire range upto the end date. Not sure what is wrong.

Issue b. If I wanted to add Device id as another query parameter,how can i do it..

```
extract = list( weather_dbh.dailyreports.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$gte": [
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$_id.day", "format": "%Y-%m-%d" }},
            start
          ]
        },
        {
          "$lt": [
            { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$_id.day", "format": "%Y-%m-%d" }},
            end
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following work as expected:

```
 mongos> var start="2020-12-05"
 mongos> var end="2020-12-06"
 mongos> var thedevice="devid"
 mongos> db.weather_dbh.dailyreports.aggregate([  {$match:{ deviceid:thedevice  , $and:[  {"_id.day":{$gte:start}}, {"_id.day":{$lt:end }}      ] } }  ])
```

Comment: My understanding was that $gte and $lt don't work with string formats.. hence was trying to convert all the datestrings to date type..

Comment: they would not work if you have the date order changed for example MM-DD-YYYY...

Comment: Ok, so as long as the datestring formats are aligned, $gt ,$lt will work with dates stored as strings..

Comment: Can you help with the second part too.. if i also want to check device id, can i add it in the same match condition in $and..

Comment: added to the answer